# Vector volume element?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I just began learning integral calculus. 
While I was learning about line, surface, and volume integrals, I realized that while the line integral and the surface integral were integrating 
vector functions, the volume integral was integrating scalar functions.

Why does the volume integral integrate scalar functions? Is there an integral that integrates vector functions over a volume?

Line integral: $\int_\vec a^\vec b \vec V\cdot d \vec l    $

Surface integral: $\int_{surface}  \vec V\cdot d \vec a$

Volume integral: $\int_{volume} T d\tau$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have $\int_{\text{volume}} \vec V \, d\tau.$ For example, the total momentum of a fluid in a region $\Omega$ is given by $\int_\Omega \rho \vec u \, dV,$ where $\rho$ is the density and $\vec u$ is the local velocity of the fluid.

Comment: Ok thank you! Then what about $\int_{volume} \vec V \cdot  d \vec  \tau$?

Comment: What is a vector volume element? In three dimensions I've never heard about such a thing, but in four dimensions the three dimensional elements can be seen as vectors, so there I could give your expression an interpretation.